# Angularjs - set view value is not updating display

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I got an input directive that should allow users to undo.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> saves the value using some function, <kbd>Esc</kbd> Cancel edits from the last save.

For the <kbd>Esc</kbd> keypress event i'm using `ngmodel.$setViewValue(scope.last_saved_value)` but the **input is not updating**. I know from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) that this function does not trigger `$digest` so i put it in an `$apply` but it is still not working.

[JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/huvejuvu/2/edit)

Comment: Please check Ivan Koshelev's answer it seems to be the **correct answer**. If so check mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually both include and require the `ngModel`:

```
app.directive('cancelableInput', function($timeout) { 
  return { 
    restrict : "A",
    require : 'ngModel', 
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=?'
    },
```

Then, when you want to change the model value and have it update, you can just do:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
  scope.ngModel = scope.last_saved_value;
});
```

Comment: Hey @dave. I guess the key here is the two way binding ? i mean, i was probably (though it really makes no sense) updating a local copy of the ng-model ?

Answer (score 39):

Try calling `ngmodel.$render();` after you do `$setViewValue`, it should help.

Comment: I thought the `$render` method should be implemented by the developer, but I guess that only applies for custom controls. Calling it for inputs (`type="checkbox"` and `type="text"` in my case) works perfectly. Thanks.